# .net cf unwanted gray borders on controls if form is disabled

Tags: compact-framework, compact-framework2.0

I am trying to implement a non blocking message box and what I do is I call another form's show method and disable the main form. However, I noticed that there are gray boxes on the form when i disabled the main form. I am currently using .net cf 2.0.  Is there a workaround to avoid this?

The showdialog works fine and i dont see that gray lines  however, it is a blocking method.

Comment: Can you attach a screen shot?  I don't fully understand the "gray boxes" statement.  Is it the borders of existing controls?

Comment: hi ctacke, sorry for the very late reply. I already talked to our third party UI provider and they provided my some settings to disable the gray boarders when the forms are disabled. :)